# Unable to save file with Thai characters filename

Tags: php

I'm currently trying to save a pdf file using mPDF library. My problem is when I try to output file using English filename, the filename is displayed correctly, but if the filename contains any Thai characters it became weird.

My mPDF outputs code.

```
$save_file = $s_code.'_'.$classroom.'.pdf';
$mpdf->Output('../../../upload/'.$save_file,'F');
```

With English filename it displayed correctly.

```
t10024_201.pdf
```

With Thai characters it doesn't.

```
เธ—เธช10024_201.pdf
```

I can't figure out what causes the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much, Anson W Han.
It's about character encoding. I finally found a solution. I simply convert the filename to Thai edcoding using "iconv" and it displays correctly.

The code:

```
$mpdf->Output('../../../upload/'.iconv("UTF-8", "TIS-620",$save_file),'F');
```

Answer (score 0):

The filename is restricted to the character set supported by the device (in this case, the server where mpdf is generating your pdfs), and doesn't actually reflect a problem with mpdf itself. [If you can add/write Thai characters within the pdf, just the filename doesn't reflect Thai characters].

You may need to configure the [Content-Disposition headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) for the webserver's response with PDF file.  As an example, see this [blog post that describes how a ColdFusion application developer dealt with saving files with French characters](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2591-embedding-foreign-characters-in-your-content-disposition-filename-header.htm).